# Update solr collection using solr-client

Tags: node.js, solr

I'm using the solr-client module for nodejs to query my solr collections.

Now I'm trying to add to and update collections in my backend code using solr-client.

I've tried http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/code/add.js.html succesfully to add data to a collection. But I don't know how to update records.

I've tried using this method (all methods can be found here: http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/code/solr.js.html);

```
    /**
     * Send an update command to the Solr server with the given `data` stringified in the body.
     *
     * @param {Object} data - data sent to the Solr server
     * @param {Function} callback(err,obj) - a function executed when the Solr server responds or an error occurs
     * @param {Error} callback().err
     * @param {Object} callback().obj - JSON response sent by the Solr server deserialized
     *
     * @return {Client}
     * @api private
     */

    Client.prototype.update = function (data, callback) {
        var self = this;
        this.options.json = JSON.stringify(data);
        this.options.fullPath = [this.options.path, this.options.core, 'update/json?commit=' + this.autoCommit + '&wt=json']
            .filter(function (element) {
                if (element) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            })
            .join('/');
        updateRequest(this.options, callback);


return self;
}
```

But how does this method knows which records to update? Does it searches for pk's in the data parameter and when it matches with your pk in the collection, it get's updated? And does it need an extra commit?

Comment: I was also stuck in this question. The solution is here via add method.

Answer (score 1):

But how does this method knows which records to update? SEE BELOW

Does it searches for pk's in the data parameter and when it matches with your pk in the collection, it get's updated?  - YES

And does it need an extra commit? - YES

Technically, u can use the INSERT as well as UPDATE. They are the same in SOLR

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/yDRlTZXqFxYGULUSf6PP?p=catalogue

Could you check out why add works, but update won't?